# Do a function while echo-ing if a certain string matches

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I have a variable that contains a subpage's content. I want to do some MySQL query, if the variable's content contains this pattern {gallery:somerandomIDnumber}, but I don't want to lose the other stuff, and it's also important that the query should run where the pattern belongs.

**For example, this is my variable's content:**

```
<h1>Title of the page</h1>
{gallery:10}
<p>Other informations...</p>
```

I tried with preg_match, but unfortunately I can't figure it out, how I can save the other content.

```
foreach($matches[0] as $value) {
    $int = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $query  = 'SELECT * ';
    $query .= 'FROM gallery_images ';
    $query .= 'WHERE gid = '.$int;
    $gallery = ms_query($query);

    while($gimage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gallery)) {
        echo '<img src="admin/uploaded/'.$gimage['imagepath'].'" width ="100">'; 
    }
}
```

Summarazing, in this situation, I want to echo the title of the page, then some pictures from my database, and after that some other text.

Comment: Is `ms_query` a function your wrote? What did you try with `preg_match`?

Comment: What is $matches array?